# How can I import mini-DV content onto a Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video, imovie, encoding

I have a number of old mini-DV tapes that I would like to import into my Macbook.

- I want an app to read the contents of these tapes
- It should be able to produce a single MP4 combining all of the clips on the tape
- It should be able to produce multiple MP4 files of the separate clips on the tape.

I tried using iMovie one time and found it to be overkill for what I need.  It imported the contents of my tape as multiple .dv files and then I have to create a project.  I don't want to deal with that.  I want to not need to manage things and import the content of tapes and store it on the filesystem so that I can watch the content on Macs/Windows/Linux/multiple-platforms.

What software meets these requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connect your camcorder and use iMovie HD to import the tape, then export using Share>Quicktime. It will create one file out of the tape.

Edit: In response to Sajee's comment below.

Choose Share>Quicktime>Compress movie for: Full Quality. As implied, there won't be any loss of quality.

[image: Share>Quicktime>Compress movie for: Full Quality]

Comment: I saw this option but will there be a loss in quality during the Export process?  I would like to maintain 100% quality, regardless of how much disk space it takes.

Comment: @Sajee See my updated answer.

Comment: @Sajee Did this work for you? If not, let me know what's not working!

Comment: MBP (10.5.8) did not detect the camera (Sony DCR-TRV7). I used the Firewire (4 in the camera to 8 in the MBP) connector that came with the camera. System Profiler did not recognize the camera.

Answer (score 3):

I have an older Canon Mini-DV camera and the process was quite painless when I brought the video in to my Mac.

1. Obtain the necessary firewire cable to connect your camera to your Mac. Honestly, this was the hardest part for me.
2. Make sure the camera is plugged in to the wall (you don't want the battery dying during import) and the tape is in the camera and set to the start of the tape.
3. Turn on the camera, turn on your Mac.
4. Connect the camera to your Mac via the firewire cable.

The Mac will open up an import dialog when you connect the camera and ask if you want to import the video in to iMovie. Say yes and iMovie's import feature will take over. It will start the video play back on your camera and you'll see it saving the video content to disk on your Mac. IIRC the import was real time (or very near too it), which is unfortunate. But really it was that simple.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new Mac app ($19 on the Mac app store) that simplifies the import and saving of MiniDV tapes.  Here it is:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lifeflix/id630212114?mt=12

this is $99 on the App Store

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and this is how I solved it:

1. Connect camera to iMovie (firewire in my case).
2. On the camera press PLAY.
3. Wait until it starts playing in the iMovie window.
4. Click `Import` in the iMovie window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [import Mini DV tapes to a Mac using macOS Catalina](https://www.aicei.net/can-i-import-mini-dv-to-mac-using-catalina/). However, please note that macOS Catalina and later versions no longer support the built-in iMovie application, which was commonly used for importing and editing Mini DV footage.

To import Mini DV tapes, you can use alternative software such as Final Cut Pro, Adobe Premiere Pro, or third-party applications like iMovie HD 6 (an older version that is compatible with macOS Catalina). These software options allow you to capture and import the Mini DV footage from your camera or deck into your Mac.

Here are the general steps to import Mini DV tapes to a Mac using compatible software:

Connect your Mini DV camera or deck to your Mac using a FireWire (IEEE 1394) cable. Ensure that your Mac has a FireWire port or use a FireWire to Thunderbolt adapter if necessary.

Open the video editing software of your choice (e.g., Final Cut Pro, Adobe Premiere Pro, or iMovie HD 6).

In the software, create a new project or open an existing one.

Access the capture settings within the software. This may vary depending on the application you're using.

Start playing the Mini DV tape from your camera or deck.

In the software, initiate the capture process. This will record the video from the Mini DV tape and save it onto your Mac's hard drive.

Once the import/capture process is complete, you can access and edit the footage within the software or transfer it to other video editing applications for further editing or sharing.

Remember that the specific steps may vary slightly depending on the software you're using. Always refer to the software's documentation or support resources for detailed instructions on importing Mini DV footage on macOS Catalina.